# Discord.js bot not sending messages

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying out discord.js and trying to send message to a specific channel using a bot. But when I run the bot, it doesn't do anything, just keeps on running continuously. The below snippet is what I tried-

```
import { Client, TextChannel } from "discord.js";

const token = "MY_BOT_TOKEN_ID"; 

console.log("Bot is starting...");

const client = new Client({
    intents: []
});
  let ChannelID = "MY_CHANNEL_ID";

client.login(token);
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is ready!");
   
});

client.on("messageCreate", () => {
    
    const channel12 = client.channels.cache.get(ChannelID) as TextChannel;
    channel12.send("Hello World");
    console.log("Message sent");
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, which is with the intents. I replaced the current intents within `Client` with `intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]` and it worked.